Delete Flyway history by script before migration is run
Is there a way to define a sql script that deletes the flyway history (and drop all tables that are create by the init script) before the flyway-migration is run.
I tried data.sql and beforeMigration.sql script but both are executed to late and the init script (flyway) is not run again.

You can drop the target tables before springboot application started:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourdatabase";
        String user = "yourusername";
        String password = "yourpassword";

        try {
            String sql = "drop table flyway_schema_history";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }


if you want to drop all the tables in your database, you can see this comment
Truncating all tables in a Postgres database
but I recommend you not to do so, if you want to repair your flyway history, you could just use the flyway repair plugin. https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/commands/repair
